# Mod-Rewrite Question

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to make a category path with pagination. URL's would be as followed;

All paths should work with or without trailing slash (if possible)

> ```
> /category/entertainment-and-music/
>
> /category/entertainment-and-music/music/
> ```
>
> (represents "music" category "under
>   entertainment and music")
>
> ```
> /category/entertainment-and-music/5/
> ```
>
> (represents 5th page for "ent. and
>   music")
>
> ```
> /category/entertainment-and-music/music/5/
> ```
>
> (represents 5th page for "ent. and
>   music/music")

I tried something like that but doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=$2
```

How can I do something flexible like that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)([/]?)$ /category.php?slug=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)([/]?)$ /category.php?slug=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)([/]?)$ /category.php?slug=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3
```

First rule should cover cases where they just specify a category.

Second rule should cover the category with a page supplied.

Third rule should cover category, sub-category, and page. I wasn't real clear on how you wanted the subcategory populated so I just wrote it out as another argument after slug.

All of them allow for an optional trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first regex also matches anything that would be caught by your second one.

/category/slugname/7/ would match the .* , with $1 set to "slugname/7"

Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/(.*)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=$2
```

At least, or tighten up your matches a bit, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/? /category.php?slug=$1&page=$2
```

That would constrain your slugs to be at least one alphanumeric character, allowing "_" and "-" as well, and your page numbers would have to be, well, numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunetely doesn't work, it returns only first part of slug, "entertainment and music". No sub-category or page number...

Comment: Two possibilities: First, perhaps the regexes should have a '$' at the end of them (after the ?), so that the string must end at that point -- otherwise, the first regex is still matching everything. Second, if that doesn't work, try switching the order of the two rules, so that the more specific rule matches first.